# 14.04 - Wireless Bad Connectivity, Slow Speeds

Tags: wireless

I've tried everything from [this article](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/), nothing helped. It's very slow while downloading, and randomly spikes up every once in a while. Something interesting I did find is after trying `sudo rmmod iwlwif`, I got "module iwlwifi is not currently loaded." Any ideas? Thanks in advance, and I know there have been plenty of questions like mine, but none of their solutions helped. If it helps at all, I have an Atheros card in a laptop.

Comment: do you know if this has been tested on other devices?

Comment: It works fine on my windows 8.1 installation on the same computer with my ubuntu partition, and works fine with every other device in the house. I've also determined that my card is an Atheros AR8162.

Comment: take you look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/291238/wireless-connected-but-slow?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that definitely improved it a bit, but I'm still pretty far from my usual download speed. The connectivity is still staying around 1-2 bars as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2Ghz and 5ghz one one wifi SSID:

- MyWifiHybrid

For me, I solved the problem by making my wifi broadcast 5ghz & 2.4ghz on SEPERATE SSIDs.

- MyWifi5G
- MyWifi2G

You can set these settings if you have a dual antennae router by going to it's config page.

May be an issue with the `iwlwifi` linux driver, since it works on Windows.